# To display images from android phone according to the most frequently used

Tags: java, android, operating-system, file-management

I am using the following statement code to display according to the last modified

```
       "final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED;"
```

now I am trying to display according to the most frequently used,

I tried

```
       "final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED;"
```

but its not working.and here is my code

```
package com.isummation.customgallery;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


@SuppressLint("InflateParams") public class AndroidCustomGalleryActivity extends Activity {
private int count;
private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
private String[] arrPath;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, 
                                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};

    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED+ "DESC";

    Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
            null, orderBy);
    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
    this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
    this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) 
    {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
        arrPath[i]= imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }
    GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    imagecursor.close();

    final Button selectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectBtn);
    selectBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
            int cnt = 0;
            String selectImages = "";
            for (int i =0; i<len; i++)
            {
                if (thumbnailsselection[i]){
                    cnt++;
                    selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";
                }
            }
            if (cnt == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please select at least one image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "You've selected Total " + cnt + " image(s).",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("SelectedImages", selectImages);
            }
        }
    });
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.galleryitem, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.checkbox.setId(position);
        holder.imageview.setId(position);
        holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                int id = cb.getId();
                if (thumbnailsselection[id]){
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                } else {
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                }
            }
        });
        holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int id = v.getId();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + arrPath[id]), "image/*");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
        holder.id = position;
        return convertView;
    }
}
class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;
    CheckBox checkbox;
    int id;
}
}
```

"

please suggest me and in advance thanks for your solution..

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED+" DESC";
```

Use it Because

i used it in my code..and it show me the latest image captured..by default order by works in ascending order,so it compares date in that order..you can use it with DATE_MODIFIED also

Comment: Why should they?  Explain.

Comment: @rayryeng i did..check it

Comment: @MeenalSharma plz check now, I have updated with my code

Comment: @rayryeng sorry,I didn't get you

Comment: @MeenalSharma ,i tried your suggestion,but still i am not getting

Comment: @user3037140 i saw your code...just add space before DESC in order by

Comment: thanksfor the suggestions,its working now,                        one small dought can i use _COUNT,on behalf of DESC?

Comment: @user3037140 no you can't as it is a keyword..you cannot change it

Comment: @MeenalSharma if need to sort according to "number of times used " , plz suggest

Comment: @MeenalSharma plz check the following link, and suggest me   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026816/displaying-images-from-the-gdrive